# search in mysql fields

Tags: mysql, search, full-text-search, field, where-clause

## I need to have a select statement that matches records partially from a field containing full names.

If a record contains john, it will display records with john, johnson, johnsmith etc. john could be anywhere within name

Answer (score 1):

```
select  
  name_field  
from  
  my_table  
where  
  name_field like '%john%'
```

**Update**:
For the question

> Do you mean to ask that "How to find, if name_field value of row1 matches full or partial with the same field value from other row2 to rowN?"

You replied  "*this is exactly what i need*".

The following solution may be helpful to you:

```
select  
 t.name_field_id, t.name_field as 'name_value',  
 d.name_field_id as 'id_of_dup', d.name_field as 'dup_in'  
from  
 my_table t,  
 my_table d  
where  
 d.name_field != t.name_field  
 and d.name_field like concat( '%', t.name_field, '%'  )  
order by name_value, dup_in;
```

Comment: i need to match to stored records to find possible duplicates not with specific text

Comment: @AhmedHosny Duplicate records or column values?

Comment: possible duplicates withing stored values, it should select the record john david and the record peter johnsmith

Comment: @AhmedHosny - This solution selects all such duplicate records. Try once on your data and check if your requirement is not met. If not met, edit your posting with sample required results.

Comment: no, it selects like 'specific text' I need to select against stored values

Comment: @AhmedHosny Do you mean to ask that *How to find, if name_field value of row1 matches full or partial with the same field value from other row2 to rowN?*

Comment: Thank you for your help, have only one table, checking within same field in same table

Comment: @AhmedHosny My solution too is on a single table.